# References missing when I checkin files to VSS 2005

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, version-control, visual-sourcesafe

I have added reference to few dlls in my VB.net Project. When I check into Visual source safe and get latest version from another machine, VS.net 2008 throws errors.

I have to add the references again in that new machine. Is there anyway where I can keep the references in spite of files checked in to VSS?

I need to send copy all the files to production server and we don't have VS.net on the production box to add reference and build the application.

Thanks

Comment: Are the references completely missing from the project, or are they just broken, i.e. do they show up with yellow warning icons next to them?

Answer (score 0):

First, be sure that the project file is checked in properly. Sometimes VS fails to regognize that the project file has changed.

A good practice is to check in all the assemblies that your project references, except the standard .NET libraries.

Another recommendation is to set up a build server, which will detect these kinds of problems early. My personal favourite is [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/).

Answer (score 0):

For references that are not in the GAC, and if they are third party things that aren't built elsewhere inhouse, a simple approach is to add the referenced assembly as a solution item (Right click on solution node | Add Existing Item). I usually put solution items in the same folder as the sln and then add the reference to that location.

When you check in the solution solution items will go into source control with it.

Use this for small relatively simple applications. If you have more than a handful of referenced solution items follow @Petter's advice and set up a build server with associated configuration management devoted to third party dependencies etc. etc.